# Commits of my project to a VisualStudio private repo I own have not appeared in 5 months?

Tags: git, visual-studio, security

I am not sure of what to make of this.

I have been making commits and pushing them to (presumably) my own private remote repo on the VisualStudio.com website off and on (I am in school so I don't always have time to work on it).

I just logged in to the website and the last commit was 9/19/2017.

I am really upset and concerned, where has my code been going and why is this happening?

I use the Git GUI/Git Bash software obtained here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check the *branch* to which you made those pushes.
By default, you see the last commit from the *`master`* branch.

But in any case, make sure those commits are still in your local repo: that would mean they are not lost, and can be pushed again.

Comment: There are more recent commits in the only other branch but the changes I *just made* are not showing up!!

Comment: Oops. My bad. I was in a panic. Yes you are correct! I was on the other branch and kept trying to push from the master branch. Thank you.